How to disable vertical scroll when horizontal scrolling on SlidingUpPanel
I am trying to reproduce the behavior that Google Maps does on the row of buttons below the title of the panel. See this video. If you see I can scroll vertically, but at the moment I start scrolling these buttons horizontally, the vertical scroll, is disabled.
I am using SlidingUpPanel (https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel), but if there is another widget that works with this request, I can change it.
Right now I have like this, and is a bit weird because while I am horizontally scrolling I can also scroll vertically.
I have tried with NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> and checking if it is horizontal scroll to disable drag on SlidingUpPanel, but it just disables scrolling after I stop scrolling horizontally.
Also, I have tried with GestureDetector with onHorizontalDragDown, onHorizontalDragUpdate, onHorizontalDragStart, onHorizontalDragEnd. But nothing really works.
Thanks in advance .

I have switched the package from sliding_up_panel to sliding_up_panel2, that provides a widget called HorizontalScrollableWidget that prevents the drag on the panel when I horizontally scroll when surrounding the Scrollable widget with it.
Hope this helps for someone else.
There is a code example:
// ...More widgets here on a Column or ListView
HorizontalScrollableWidget(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
            children: [
                // ...The rest of the widgets here
            ],
        ),
    ),                    
),
// ...More widgets here on a Column or ListView


If (using NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>):

it just disables scrolling after I stop scrolling horizontally.

Then I think the problem is there, try reenabling the scrolling after stopping the horizontal scrolling.
like this:
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (notification) {
            if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              if (notification.scrollDirection   
 == ScrollDirection.horizontal) {
                panelController.isDraggable = false;
              } else {
                panelController.isDraggable = true;
              }
            }
            return true;
          },

If you already tried that then please add a link to your code in Git Hub so we can understand the problem more clearly.
